# Unique Solution to 1st Order Autonomous ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, inverse-function-theorem

Take the ODE $y'=F(y)$. Show it has a unique solution with initial condition $y(t_0) = y_0$ in a neighborhood of $t_0$ provided $F$ in continuous and $F(y_0) \neq 0$. I am trying to use the inverse function theorem by solving the ODE the inverse function satisfies but I am getting stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODE
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = F(y)
$$
seems to separate into
$$
dx = \frac{dy}{F(y)} \iff x = \int \frac{dy}{F(y)} = \int f(y) dy,
$$
where $f(y) = 1/F(y)$. Can you prove $f$ is integrable?

---

**UPDATE** After your response, we then understand that $f$ is integrable, therefore we conclude that there is some anti-derivative $\phi$ of $f$, so $t = \phi(y) + C$ and we enforce the initial condition, calculating
$$
C = t_0 - \phi(y_0),
$$
so the final unique solution looks like
$$
t - t_0 = \phi(y) - \phi(y_0).
$$

Comment: I understood up to here myself, this is where I get stuck. What I understand is because F is nonzero and continuous, f is continuous and bounded which implies its integrable over a fixed interval.

Comment: @justaguy see the update. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @justaguy It is indeed true that every continuous bounded function on some interval has a continuous bounded antiderivative on the same interval.

Comment: why do we know this is unique though? is just because we have found the one solution?

Comment: @justaguy yes. Any other solution would either violate the integration (which gives you a form) or the initial condition (which forces the $C$ value)

Comment: alright good, that's what I thought, thank you for the help!